# Save button click function not working in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Hi guys i have a table where i have a edit the project link ...when i click on that it takes me to a Edit page where i have textboxes for editing  record and a button to Save..but i click on Save button its not working can any one help me where am i doing wrong here is my code

This is my `Edit.aspx` page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Gridview_BugTracker.Models.BugTracker_DataHelper>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
 <title></title>
        <%: ViewBag.Title="Edit" %>
</head>
<body>
        <div>
             <% using (Html.BeginForm())
                 { %>
        <form action="Edit.aspx" method="post"></form>

        <%:Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
        <fieldset>
                <legend>Projects</legend>

             <%:Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectId)%>

                <div class="editor-label">
                     <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.projectName)%>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                        <%:Html.EditorFor(model => model.projectName)%>
                        <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.projectName)%>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                        <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)%>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                        <%:Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)%>
                        <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)%>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                        <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.status)%>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                        <%:Html.EditorFor(model => model.status)%>
                        <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.status)%>
                </div>
                <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                </p>
        </fieldset>
<%} %>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")%>
        </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

---

And this is my controller function:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, BugTracker_DataHelper updatemodel)
{
    SqlConnection editconn = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Data Source=SSDEV6\SQLEXPRESS");
    {
            editconn.Open();
            SqlCommand ecmd = new SqlCommand("Select ProjectId,projectName,Description,status From Projects Where ProjectId=" + id, editconn);                 
            SqlDataReader dr = ecmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                    updatemodel.ProjectId = Convert.ToInt16(dr["ProjectId"]);
                    updatemodel.projectName = dr["projectName"].ToString();
                    updatemodel.Description = dr["Description"].ToString();
                    updatemodel.status = dr["status"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                    dr.Close();
            }
            dr.Close();
            editconn.Close();
            return View(updatemodel);
    }
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(BugTracker_DataHelper updatemodel, FormCollection collection, int id)
{
    SqlConnection editconn = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Data Source=SSDEV6\SQLEXPRESS");
    {

            SqlCommand ecmd = new SqlCommand("EditGetList", editconn);
            ecmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            editconn.Open();
            ecmd.Parameters.Add("projectID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = updatemodel.ProjectId;
            ecmd.Parameters.Add("projectName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = updatemodel.projectName;
            ecmd.Parameters.Add("Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = updatemodel.Description;
            ecmd.Parameters.Add("Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = updatemodel.status;
            editconn.Close();   

            return View(updatemodel);
    }
}
```

---

when i click on SAVE button in aspx page it should go to Edit method in my controller .....what am i doing wrong here.........

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the Post Edit action is it being hit? Your form action being edit.aspx looks incorrect unless you have amended your routes.

Comment: See my answer below. Also your question from yesterday was similar to this and I answered. Did my answer work? If so you need to accept peoples answers. Cheers.

Comment: @Rory....Already edit page came edid the data but when edit the data and click save button is not work out....

Comment: @Gaz ... your answer also am saw i think that is workble....stil am nt getting what am wrong.........

Comment: @RaghavendraBandaru What actually happens when you click Edit? Do you get an error message? Have you set a breakpoint to see if it actually gets to the Edit Post method?

Comment: @GazWinter ... no error came ..but only when i click the save button not work out.......i was put the Breakpoint bt nt goto edit funtion.......

Comment: @RaghavendraBandaru Do you have firebug installed? If so then open the Net tab and watch where it tries to go when you click Save. Tell me what the result is.

Comment: @GazWinter.... ..i was put the Break pont in aspx page bt nt goto this method .. <form action="Edit.aspx" method="post"></form> what happned i dnt knw.......

Comment: It wont go to that page because the button is not part of that form. Its part of the parent form. See my edited answer for more info

Comment: @GazWinter....THanks u now Save Bittton working now ....edit the data but not channg the data....in database no chang the data show the provious data.........

Answer (score 0):

Are you suppsed to have two forms?

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
{ %>
     <form action="Edit.aspx" method="post"></form>
```

Or were you trying to set the action of your BeginForm?

The button that you are pressing is actually a part of the first form and not the second.

So this

```
 <form action="Edit.aspx" method="post"></form>
```

is currently not doing very much.

If you want the save button to be doing something in the second form then you will need to put the button inside the form tags like so:

```
 <form action="Edit.aspx" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
 </form>
```